# Add entire folder to packaging Winrt in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a folder `Assets/source`. It has a lot of files (.png,.xml ...) and also divided with sub folders inside. Is it possible to have them all copy to the output directory without manually setting them one by one? or to copying this folder to  `/LocalState` at runtime?
[image]

I have tried adding it to paths, I cant seem to find it in the installation folder after install. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this from the IDE, but you can definitely use `*` in paths in MSBuild files, e.g. you could include `Assets/source/*` to pick up all of the files from that directory.

Comment: I have added to paths but didn't work. if I add * to it, it way say directory not valid.

Comment: You can multi-select items and set them all to copy. You can also set a pre-build event to copy the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy and paste them to `Assets/...` 
   (By default, Build Action is Content , Copy to output is Do not copy. Leave it at default)
2. During run time : 
   `StorageFolder sourceFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assests/...");`

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, select all the files that you want copied to the output directory, and in the "Properties" window, change the setting in "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy Always".
I don't think you could do that to the entire folder though.